# Looking to identify a children's novel in which stowaways eventually crash on the moon

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, childrens-novel, artificial-gravity, moon

I'm trying to remember the title/author of a juvie SF novel from the mid-late 50s.

There are two kids who sneak out every chance they get to watch rocket launches. These are multi-staged things with winged space shuttles perched atop them, like the old Von Braun Colliers designs.

Somehow - don't recall how - they end up accidentally trapped on one of these as it lifts off and - again, I don't recall how - they end up stranded in orbit. Once there, they're rescued by a cylindrical, privately-owned spacecraft that rotates to simulate gravity.

The crew are friendly, and they make them a pizza. As they're two painfully Caucasian suburban kids, they don't really know what such exotic foreign food is, and the book has to explain it to us, the readers.

Eventually - again, for reasons I don't recall - the ship crashes on the moon.